# If one system has a feasible solution then other does not have

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

If we have 2 linear equality and inequatlity systems:

$(1)$ $A x < = b $ $ x >= 0$.

$(2)$ $b^T y < 0, A^T y > = 0, y >= 0$

where A $in$ $R^mxn$ and c $in$ $R^n$ are given and x $in$ $R^n$ and y $in$ $R^m$ are decision variables.
Prove that exactly one of the two systems (1) and (2) has a feasible solution. Which means that 1 has a feasible solution iff (2) does not have a feasible solution.

I have troubles doing the forward part of the proof and understanding it geometrically.

I imagine the forward part of the proof to be something like if there exists, $x>=0$ that satisfies the constraint of the primal problem and is thus feasible primal problem.. I don't know how to proceed further. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $(1)$ is feasible.  Suppose on the contrary that $(2)$ is feasible as well.

We have $Ax \le b$ and  $y \ge 0$.

Hence $y^TAx\le y^Tb$.

Since $y^TA \ge 0$ and $x \ge 0$, hence $y^TAx \ge 0$ but this contradicts $y^Tb < 0$.

Edit:

For the other direction, if the primal is infeasible, then the dual is either unbounded or infeasible. However, since $y=0$ is a feasible solution to $(D)$, we conclude that it is unbounded. Hence we can find a $y$ that satisfy $(2)$.

Comment: How did you get $y^T A \ge 0$  and $x \ge 0 $ and hence $y^T Ax \ge 0$

Comment: Try to prove that if $u^T \ge 0$ and $v \ge 0$, then $u^Tv \ge 0$.

Comment: well, yes I am aware when you multiply two positive vectors then the result indeed will be positive, but I am concerned about getting $y^T A \ge 0 $ in the first place

Comment: that is assumption from contradiction.

Comment: So, just for my own personal clarification(hope you can validate), we take the constraint from(1), as $y \ge 0 $ it implies $y^T \ge 0$ then we multiple this vector on our constraint $Ax \le b $. Following this, we revist our assumption that $y^T A > = 0$ and $x >= 0$ which is a contradiction to $y^T b < 0$

Comment: I attempted to the following, if x is a feasible point and if $A^T x  \ge y$ then our $min(Ax)^T y \ge 0 $ which means that (2) cannot hold true for the minimization problem.

Comment: please explain more, I can't follow your reasoning. what do you mean by $A^T \ge y$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116360/discussion-between-ishaan-singh-and-siong-thye-goh).